# Can we download historical data for ALL stocks listed in NSE using Quandl in R?

Tags: r, quandl

I am using the Quandl API in R to download the historical stock market data listed in NSE India.
The below code gives me the historical data for ICICI and PNB but needs manual entries for each stock to fetch the data. How do we download the historical data for all the stocks listed in NSE without writing these manual statements for each stock.

```
library(Quandl)
Quandl.api_key("API_Key")
## Download the data Set
ICICI = Quandl("NSE/ICICIBANK",collapse="daily",start_date="2018-01-01",type="raw")
PNB= Quandl("NSE/PNB",collapse="daily",start_date="2018-01-01",type="raw")
## Add another ("Stock") coloumn in Datasets using cbind command
ICICI<-cbind(ICICI,Stock="")
PNB<-cbind(PNB,Stock="")
## Paste the stock name in stock column
ICICI$Stock<-paste(ICICI$Stock,"ICICI",sep="")
PNB$Stock<-paste(PNB$Stock,"PNB",sep="")
## Consolidate under one dataset
Master_Data<-rbind(ICICI,PNB)
```

I do have a list of all the stocks name in an excel file as follows.

```
NSE/20MICRONS
NSE/3IINFOTECH
NSE/3MINDIA
NSE/A2ZMES
NSE/AANJANEYA
NSE/AARTIDRUGS
NSE/AARTIIND
NSE/AARVEEDEN
NSE/ABAN
NSE/ABB
NSE/ABBOTINDIA
NSE/ABCIL
NSE/ABGSHIP
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I hope it will be running for you too.

I have tested it.

Make a list (lyst in the code) items of all the companies for you want the data, like below. Then use `lapply` to save everything in a new list, like `lyst_dwnld` in the code.

If you want to avoid manually typing all that name as list, then you can save your excel sheet of names as a data frame and then use the same concept as below.

**Code:**

```
lyst <- list(icici = "NSE/ICICIBANK", pnb = "NSE/PNB")

lyst_dwnld <- lapply(names(lyst),
    function(x)Quandl(lyst[[x]],
                      collapse="daily",
                      start_date="2018-01-01",type="raw"))
```

**Output**:

YOu can check if the data is downloaded or not, by quickly seeing the head.

```
> lapply(lyst_dwnld, head,2)
[[1]]
        Date  Open   High   Low   Last  Close Total Trade Quantity Turnover (Lacs)
1 2018-05-25 298.4 300.95 294.6 296.20 295.65             13541580        40235.19
2 2018-05-24 293.7 299.00 291.2 298.15 297.70             11489424        33952.28

[[2]]
        Date  Open  High   Low  Last Close Total Trade Quantity Turnover (Lacs)
1 2018-05-25 81.95 84.55 81.30 83.60 83.35             19102160        15875.32
2 2018-05-24 80.70 82.50 80.05 82.35 82.10             19933989        16229.67
```

---

**EDITED:**

In you are unable to make a list using a dataframe, here is what you can do.

1) Read your data in excel to R dataframe using (`readxl`). 
2) I have read a sample data and called it df.

```
df <- readxl::read_excel('path_where_excel_resides_with_name_of_excel_and_extension')
```

3) Name the column, something meaningful. I just used "name" here for this single column excel.

```
names(df) <- "name"
```

4) Use strsplit, to split the column(keep the original column), fetech only the second name out of it.

```
df$co_name <- lapply(strsplit(df$name, "/"),`[[`,2)
```

Now you can create the lyst object which is used in earlier code.

```
lyst <- as.list(df$name)
names(lyst) <- df$co_name
```

Please let me know in case this doesn't work out for you or in case of any issues. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So in the 3rd and 4th step you are creating a new column which will just have name of the stock like ICICI, PNB etc instead of NSE/ICICI. Correct ? I did not understand the last part where  you are downloading the historical data for each of these stocks and tagging it against the name you created in 3rd step.

Comment: @Akash you are correct, downloading of data is happening in the **code** section above.. the 4th step is not downloading , 4th step is is creation tags for thesr stocks. Please let me know if you are still in doubt

Comment: library(Quandl)
Quandl.api_key("API_Key")
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/akjain/Downloads/NSE-datasets-codes/NSE-datasets-codes.csv") 
df$Code <- substr(df$StockCode,5,26)

lyst <- as.list(df$StockCode)

lyst_dwnld <- lapply(names(lyst),
                     function(x)Quandl(lyst[[x]],
                                       collapse="daily",
                                       start_date="2018-01-01",type="raw"))                              This is giving me lyst_dwnld as null. When I checked names(lyst) is shows null. I am not expert in R as I am using R just to get the source file.

Comment: can you see anything on `df$StockCode`, by printing it.I am also not sure what is the use of df$Code here. also you are not giving names to `lyst`  like i did in the code like this, `names(lyst) <- df$columnlabels`, here columnlabels is having value as "icici", "pnb" etc.

Comment: df$StockCode has values like NSE/ICICI, NSE/PNB. Yes it has values if I print it. df$Code has values like ICICI, PNB. I am getting StockCode from my csv file. And I am creating new column Code by using substring. When I use your code to download data it does not tag the stock name with the data in the dataframe. If you can help me with the consolidated code that will be of great help.  The csv has data something like below.                                                                        StockCode Name
NSE/ICICIBANK ICICI Bank Limited
NSE/PNB Punjab National Bank

Comment: @Akash ,its already there in the code so, you should do something like...`df$Code <- lapply(strsplit(df$StockCode, "/"),`[[`,2)`, it should work, so here strsplit will split your stockcode into two strings, I will take only the second string which contain the values as icici, pnb etc, that is in above code 2 is there, `[[` is a subsetting function to fetch nd splitted value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171976/discussion-between-akash-and-pkumar).

Comment: @Akash please come to the chat

Answer (score 0):

The data is available until 2018 only via **Quandl**.

You can use **BatchGetSymbols** library in R to download further data. There is one issue that I noticed while downloading from Yahoo finance was that sometimes the data was missing for a few months in a year. Advised to use with caution before implementing any analysis and check the consistency of the data.

The following code is for reference:

```
if (!require(BatchGetSymbols)) install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')
#Package to download yahoo finance stock prices from internet directly    
library(BatchGetSymbols) 

first.date <- Sys.Date() - (365*5) #5 years back
last.date <- Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'monthly' #change it as you like. example:'daily'

tickers <- c('RELIANCE.NS','TCS.NS')
# Reliance, Tcs 

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(your_directory_path,"stock_prices")) 

str(l.out)
# To check download status of all stocks
l.out$df.control

# Actual Stock prices downloaded
head(l.out$df.tickers)
```

## Alternate Method

I found this link during my web browsing and I am yet to implement it after understanding. Hopefully, this might help you further.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/extracting-eod-data-from-nse/